# android studio, level and platform issue

Tags: android

```
      I have android studio. It seems that I have an API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W  as Android Virtual Device which is a no no.
```

Can any one tell me step by step (or guide me to a link) that will show me how to put a Level  19 and

Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV.

This is the first time I download a program but am familiarizing myself with the source code files.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just open the SDK manager located under tools->Android->SDK Manager.

All the SDK's and necessary files are available there for download.

Once you downloaded the content it should just work.